# Parallel execution of functions in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

This is simplified, toy example, but basically, how can I get two function to work in parallel, in the following manner:

```py
def loop():
    test = 0
    while(test < 3):
        test += 1
        print('doing A stuff')
        #stuff_needed_in_A = concurrent(test) #I don't want this
        print(stuff_needed_in_A)

def concurrent(attribute_of_A):
    # this function should not be used in A, directly, just what it returns
    print('doing B stuff') 
    stuff_needed_in_A = 2*attribute_of_A
    return stuff_needed_in_A

stuff_needed_in_A = None
loop()
```

**concurrent(attribute_of_A)** needs data from **loop()** at each iteration, (in real time, so storing it somehow is not an option). At the same time, at each iteration, whatever **concurrent(attribute_of_A)** is needed in **loop()**.

I cannot use **concurrent(attribute_of_A)** directly in **loop()**, because I am trying to separate two very different tasks, each in its own module and class.

I think this can be done with parallelization but I have no idea how and it would help me a lot of someone could explain how it's done. (Or a workaround, or why it cannot be done, in which case I'll just design the classes differently)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: To be fair, the XY Problem can apply to any question that doesn't include the entire 1000 lines block of code. But I see your point and it's very valid

Comment: `XY Problem` is when we asked for help in debugging  a ***solution*** instead of solving the actual ***problem***. .